# smalltalk: about method- "withArgs:executeMethod:"

Tags: smalltalk, squeak

I'm trying to understand the method "withArgs: executeMethod: " in smalltalk, squeak.

**1. I am trying to understand what is the role of the method?
2. What arguments need to be passed to it for it to be carried out?**

Answer (score 4):

A good way to understand this method is by considering it as a syntactic variant of the general expression

```
  object msg: arg                      (*)
```

where `object` is the receiver of the message with selector `msg:` and `arg` its argument. There are of course variants with no or multiple arguments, but the idea is the same.

When `object` receives this message (*) the Virtual Machine (VM) looks up for the `CompiledMethod` with selector `msg:` in the `object`'s hierarchy, and transfers it the control, binding `self` to `object` and the formal argument of the method to `arg`.

Notice that this *invocation* is managed by the VM, no by the Virtual Image (VI). So, how could we reflect the same in the VI? Well, there are two steps in this behavior (1) find the method and (2) bind its formal receiver and arguments to the actual ones and let it run.

Step (1) is the so called *lookup* algorithm. It is easily implemented in Smalltalk: just ask the receiver its class, check whether the class includes the selector `#msg:` and, if not, go to the superclass and repeat. If all checks fail, issue the `doesNotUnderstand:` message.

Step (2) exactly requires what `#withArgs:executeMethod:` provides. It allows us to say

```
   object withArgs: {arg} executeMethod: method
```

where `method` is the `CompiledMethod` found in step (1). [We have to use `{arg}` rather than `arg` because the plural in `withArgs:` suggests that the method expects an `Array` of arguments.]

**Why would we want this?**

Generally speaking, giving the VI the capability to mimic behavior implemented in the VM is good because it makes metaprogramming easier (and more natural).

More practically, a relevant example of the use of this capability is the implementation of Method Wrappers. Briefly described, given any particular method, you can wrap it (as the `wrappee`) inside a `wrapper` method, which also has a `preBlock`. If you then substitute the original method in the `MethodDictionary` where it belongs, with the `wrapper`, you can let the `wrapper` first execute the `preBlock` and then the intended method. The first task is easy: just send the message `preBlock value`. For the second we have the method (the `wrappee`), the receiver and the arguments (if any). So, to complete the task you only need to send to the receiver `withArgs:executeMethod:` with the actual argument(s) and the `wrappee`.

Ah! Let's not forget to mention that one of the reasons for having Method Wrappers is to measure testing coverage.

Note also that `withArgs:executeMethod:` does not require the second argument, i.e., the method to execute, to be in any class, let alone the class of the receiver. In particular, you could create a `CompiledMethod` on the fly and execute it on any given object. Of course, it is up to you to make sure that the execution will not crash the VM by, say, using the third ivar of the receiver if the receiver has only two etc. A simple way to create a `CompiledMethod` without installing it in any class is by asking the Smalltalk compiler to do so (look for senders of `newCompiler` to learn how to do that).